Exception not propagating in calling method
I have a method abc() in which the request is forwarded to other controller actions based on some condition. Is it possible to catch exception thrown in oneMethod of class oneController inside catch of abc() method? I am putting code for reference -
Main method -->
Class abc{
void abc(int findMethod) {
        try {
            if (params.findMethod == 1) {
                forward(controller: 'oneController', action: 'oneMethod')
                return
            } else {
                forward(controller: 'twoController', action: 'twoMethod')
                return
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error while downloading ICSR Report", ex)
        }

    }
}

Called Method -->
Class oneController {
 void oneMethod() {
        if (someCondition) {
            throw new ArithmeticException("no data found")
        }
    }
}

I don't want to change the code for oneMethod or twoMethod. Can I somehow catch these exceptions inside abc() ?

shouldn't be too hard to test yourself (in posted code there is no call to oneMethod() - there is something hidden that we cannot see...)

What language is this?

Hi @tgdavies, I am working on a grails project with groovy programming language.

Hi @user85421, is it related to the fact that forward method clears the output buffer and therefore returns nothing to the invoking method? Please help if I am wrong or right.
